# Make child visible outside an overflow: scroll parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I had a calendar inside a container.
I set the container to scrollable, but when my calendar overflow, then it was cut off.
How could I make it visible?

pls refer to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cookies-xhw1m

here are my project screenshot, hope its will helper for guys to imagine what I want.

[project sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdtuo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your design for it, but just to make it visible, you can use `position: relative` on the .modal and

```
position: absolute;
bottom: -50px;
```

for the `.input_field--date`

Comment: I had added a  screenshot, hope its will helpful to imagine.

Comment: oh, I see, you wanna see the full-size widget. I would suggest putting a min-height on the outer container for at least header + calendar height. Also, you can remove the position relative from `input_field--date` and position absolute `.calendar.input_field--date__calendar`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I need the calendar could up above the input field when it too close bottom side, so I need absolute to help me do this.